# Java. Change class declaration at runtime

Tags: java, classloader, javaagents, redeploy

Everybody knows Jrebel. But I wanted to make some small similar implementation - just a functionality that allows to reload Class definition after recompilation.

I made java agent that monitors classes. Also I specify system classloader that loads all my custom classes. And after recompilation my agent should reload class with new definition. But nothing happens.

Also I tried to use instrumentation API within my java agent:

```
instrumentation.redefineClasses
```

or

```
instrumentation.retransformClasses
```

but it doesn't help.

All the source files can be found here - https://github.com/ice-pro/Runtime-Redeploy

To run test please execute 'install' on main module and then 'compile' on Tester module.

Please advice me how can I redefine class declaration at runtime.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you show us the code of your agent and how you're registering it with the JVM.  As is, we've nothing to go on.

Comment: I have just updated the question. Sources added.

Comment: Have you looked at [JDWP.VirtualMachine.RedefineClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jpda/jdwp/jdwp-protocol.html#JDWP_VirtualMachine_RedefineClasses)?